# web interface for omxplayer useig nodejs

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

Is there a Node.js module to control omxplayer via web interface for raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The omx-control module works by emulating keypresses. The omx-interface module handles communication via DBus and can also perform GET stuff. Like get duration and get position. There is a nice web interface thats included in the package.
[npm page of omx-interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/omx-interface)
For openness sake: As I created the module I might be biased towards omx-interface unjustly.

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for some modules. Found your question and answer to it by just googling. Visit this page https://npmjs.org/package/omxcontrol. I am not sure if some out of the box component is available.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest [omxdirector](https://npmjs.org/package/omxdirector). It does not use fifo like `omxcontrol`, but native *pipe*. It supports also loop playing with [omxplayer fork by pasky](https://github.com/pasky/omxplayer).